# Getting 'java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input' while using Postman

Tags: json, web-services, postman, content-type, webservice-client

I am using Chrome extension - Postman app to test my webservice. Below is the template of my webservice -

```
@POST
@Path("/usertransaction/get/amount")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public List<ABCForm> getAmount(List<ABCForm> abclist, Date asOfDate) {
.
.
.   
}
```

I have set header as `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and request body as below -

```
 [
    {
        "ccc":"1",
        "qqq":"22",
        "acac":"24",
        "abc":"100"
    }
],
"asOfDate":"05/05/2018"
```

I am aware that its not a valid `JSON`. But even if i resolve JSON issue, it still throws the same exception. I am looking for proper JSON through which request could be made and resolve this exception.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *But even if i resolve JSON issue* Let us know how do you resolve valid json issue?

Comment: i only pass the array object, but it still gives same error. It seemsissue related to POSTMAN. currently i am passing values in RAW body.If i pass values in FORM option with following values - `abclist[0][ccc]:12
abclist[0][qqq]:11
abclist[0][acac]:11
abclist[0][abc]:2121
asOfDate:05/05/2018` , error changes to `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@d987808; line: 1, column: 3]`